# Abnormal Spark dataframe transformation

Tags: python, apache-spark

Sorry for the terrible title. I don't know how else to describe it.

what I'm looking for is how to transform a dataframe that looks like

```
+---+----+---+
| id|name|age|
+---+----+---+
|  1| Tim|123|
|  1| Bob|456|
|  2| Amy|789|
|  3| Tom|101|
+---+----+---+
```

into a data frame that looks like

```
+------+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
|1-name|1-age|2-name|2-age|3-name|3-age|
+------+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
|   Tim|  123|   Amy|  789|   Tom|  101|
|   Bob|  456|  null| null|  null| null|
+------+-----+------+-----+------+-----+
```

Comment: Could you explain the rules?

Answer (score 0):

This "abnormal" transformation is called a *pivot*, and it was implemented in Spark 1.6. [Link to Python docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot)

More reading material:

- https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html
- https://www.svds.com/pivoting-data-in-sparksql/